# Overlayfs as a solution to copying central file systems everywhere. In what way?

Tags: linux, filesystems, linux-kernel, overlayfs, union-mount

I have searched the whole internet and have watched my lecture multiple times just to understand one thing: I still can't quite understand, how is overlayFS a solution to copying the central FS for each user?

Is the lowerdir set to be the root directory? Or do we create an alternative rootfs and use it everywhere as a lowerdir for each new filesystem for each user?

I apologize but there's some understanding gap. I don't understand in what way are we saving storage, and if someone could just put it in simple terms, it would be wonderful. Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "central filesystem"? You allude to "saving storage" - I don't think that this is the main purpose of an OverlayFS. Perhaps quote the relevant passage from your lecture, pointing out what precisely you don't understand.

Comment: @berndbausch Yes I know overlayFS has a different main purpose, the issue I'm having is understanding in what way is it better than the following: copying the root files on each new file system that we eventually jail in terms of storage